# Собрать jar на maven

Tags: java, maven, jar

Нашёл рабочий билд, вроде всё как надо. Но теперь проблема в том, что idea компилирует проект и никаких ошибок не кидает, однако если через командную строку запускать jar'ник, то высвечивает, то что на скрине.

```
<build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.6</source>
                        <target>1.6</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                                <mainClass>com.exsposit.practica.Main</mainClass>
                                <packageName>com.exsposit.practica</packageName>
                                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                                <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <includeScope>compile</includeScope>
                                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>


        </build>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Классы которые запускаются

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        new FileWorker(args);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class FileWorker {
    public FileWorker(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
        new ArgumentParser(args);
    }
}
```

---

```
public ArgumentParser(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        if (args.length != 6) {
            System.err.println("Please, write number of the arguments correctly");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {

            if (args[i].equals("-f")) {
                fileFormat = getFileFormat(args[i+1]);

                if(!isFileNameCorrect(args[i + 1])) {
                    file = args[++i];
                } else {
                    System.err.println("Check file's name to symbols '^, ?, etc.'");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            } else if (args[i].equals("-p")) {
                path = args[++i];
            } else if (args[i].equals("-t")) {
                threads = args[++i];
            }
        }


        if(fileFormat.equals(".csv")) {
            new Loader(path, new CsvParser(file).parse(), threads).download();
        }

        if(fileFormat.equals(".json")) {
            new Loader(path, new JsonParser(file).parse(), threads).download();
        }

        if(fileFormat.equals(".xml")) {
            new Loader(path, new XmlParser(file).parse(), threads).download();
        }

    }

    private boolean isFileNameCorrect(String name) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.+)?[><\\|\\?*/:\\\\\"](.+)?");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(name);
        return !matcher.find();
    }

    private String getFileFormat(String args) {
        int index = args.indexOf('.');
        return index == -1 ? null : args.substring(index);
    }

    protected void finalize() throws IOException {
        file = null;
        path = null;
        fileFormat = null;

    }

}
```

---

```
public class LoaderBean {

    private int countTreads = 0;

    protected void download(List<File> files, String path, String nThreads) {


        int n = Integer.parseInt(nThreads);
        int nLastThreadsNumber = files.size() % n;
        java.lang.Thread[] threads;

        while(countTreads < files.size()) {
            if(countTreads + nLastThreadsNumber == files.size()) {
                threads = new java.lang.Thread[nLastThreadsNumber];
            }
            else {
                threads = new java.lang.Thread[n];
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < n && j + countTreads != files.size(); ++j) {
                threads[j] = new java.lang.Thread(new Thread(files.get(countTreads + j), path),
                        String.format("Thread %d", j));
            }

            if(countTreads + threads.length <= files.size()) {
                countTreads = countTreads + threads.length;
            }
            startThreads(threads);
        }
    }

    private static void startThreads(java.lang.Thread[] threads) {
            for (java.lang.Thread thread : threads) {
                thread.start();
                continue;

            }
    }
}

class Thread implements Runnable {

    private String path;
    private com.exsposit.practica.Beans.File file;

    Thread(com.exsposit.practica.Beans.File file, String path){
        this.path = path;
        this.file = file;
    }

    public  void run() {
        new Downloader(file.getUrl(), path, file.getName()).startDownload();
        System.out.println(java.lang.Thread.currentThread().getName());
        System.out.println(" ============================== ");
    }

}
```

Это основыне классы, счас ещё парсинг покажу

```
public class JsonParser implements IParse{

    private String file;

    private List<File> jsonFilesList = new ArrayList<File>();

    public JsonParser(String file) {
        this.file = file;

    }

    public List<File> parse() throws IOException{

        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        try {
            jsonObject = (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(new FileReader(file));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("DownloadFiles");

        Iterator arrayIterator = jsonArray.iterator();

        while (arrayIterator.hasNext()) {
            JSONObject jsonFileAttributes = (JSONObject) arrayIterator.next();
            File file = new File();
            file.setName((String) jsonFileAttributes.get("name"));
            file.setUrl((String) jsonFileAttributes.get("url"));
            jsonFilesList.add(file);
        }

        return jsonFilesList;

    }
}
```

---

```
public interface IParse {
    List<File> parse() throws IOException, ParseException;
}
```

ParseExaption хз почему

Comment: Также вопрос, нужно где-то в pom.xml прописывать, что на входе будут атрибуты подаваться?

Comment: нет, в поме не надо писать

Comment: @batman вы можете глянуть и сказать почему кидает parseexaption?

Answer (score 5):

Добавь после описания артефакта в POM файл

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

Comment: не совсем понял куда вставить, в какой конкретно тэг

Comment: после <artifactId>blablabla</artifactId>

Comment: вообще не имеет значения особо после чего ты положишь главное чтобы в корне <project>

Comment: я уже с этим разобрался, с ошибкой parseExeption можете помочь?

Comment: Код в студию, у тебя проблема в мейне но почему то jni рроблема . давай код

Comment: какой класс кидать, у меня их много. Сча подправлю

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>Project</groupId>
    <artifactId>blablabla</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0.jre8</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                                <mainClass>pakkket.MainClassDbo</mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: кидает ту ошибку, что я на скрине показал выше. Но проект собирается без ошибок

Comment: можете глянуть ошибку?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>app</groupId>
    <artifactId>app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <dependencies>

    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>package.Main</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>

</project>
```